# Calling delegate methods from extension throws nill, but works on action event

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, extension-methods, swift4.2

Below is the code snippet, `delegate` never calls when `XMPPStreamDelegate` methods called periodically. Presence service `delegate` throws `nil` inside of extension but gives value when calling some action from another view controller.

```swift
public protocol PresenceServiceDelegate{
    func didPresenceReceive()
}

class PresenceService: NSObject{ 
    var delegate: PresenceServiceDelegate?

    public override init()
        delegate = self
     }
}

extension PresenceService: XMPPStreamDelegate {

    public func didReceive presence() // XMPPStrem delegate

        // My Presence Service delegate not at all calling (delegate throws nil )
        delegate?.didPresenceReceive()
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController{
    var presence = PresenceService()

    func viewDidLoad() {
        presence.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: PresenceServiceDelegate {
    public func didPresenceReceive(){
        print("test")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you override viewDidLoad in a class that is not a subclass of UIViewController? Post code that compile, otherwise it is almost impossible to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson its the sample code snippet replicating the same for my complete code base that I'm working on. I can't post the entire code here since its bunch of lines code. The issue here is PresenceService delegate never executed from the extension on xmppstreamdelegate method when the method gets called. I would like to get the value thru didPresenceReceive delegate method that should returns the value to viewcontroller's PresenceServiceDelegate extension whenever get a call from xmppstreamdelegate.

Comment: And where do you call viewDidLoad in your code?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry, just edited the code. Init will call when instance created from viewcontroller and sets delegate for xmppstreamdelegate. xmppstreamdelegate methods calling correctly but the issue is presenceservicedelegate not calling as it should throw an expected value to the viewcontroller's extension.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for your responses, I've just created singleton for presenceservice class and call the delegates from xmppstreamdelegate methods. things works cool!  PresenceService.sharedInstance.delegate.didPresenceReceive()

Answer (score 0):

The Below code works fine as expected. During XMPPStreamDelegate calls presenceservice delegate object throws nill and not recognised, here the below code calling instance of presenceservice's class which enabling it's own delegate instance and triggered value to the view controller as expected.

```
class PresenceService: NSObject{ 
    var delegate: PresenceServiceDelegate?

     public override init()
        delegate = self
     }

    // Singleton instance
    public class var sharedInstance : PresenceService {
        struct PresenceServiceInstance {
            static let instance = PresenceService()
        }
        return PresenceServiceInstance.instance
    }
}

extension PresenceService: XMPPStreamDelegate {

    public func didReceive presence() // XMPPStrem delegate

        // My Presence Service delegate not at all calling (delegate throws nil )
        PresenceServiceInstance.sharedInstance.delegate?.didPresenceReceive()
    }
}
```